# Is there a lower bound on the number of ones in the binary representations of powers of three?

Tags: exponentiation, binary, upper-lower-bounds

The number of ones in the binary representation of $3^n$ seems to continually increase as $n$ gets larger. Is there a known lower bound or is this still an unsolved problem? Looking at $n < 270.000$ the number of ones seems to always be more than $\frac{3}{4}n$ and grows at a pretty consistent rate. [This data](https://gist.github.com/lcnr/f9cc2ea7a66027803c9710c1af258266) and the [used rust program](https://gist.github.com/lcnr/83e78a6315f4fa3b75b28d4a5ed29f7b) can both be found on github.

Comment: Well, the binary expansion of $3^n$ has about $n\log_23\approx 1.585n$ digits. You would expect about half of them, or $0.7925n$, to be $1$, which agrees with your experiments. But this kind of thing is usually very hard to prove.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sequence is [A011754](http://oeis.org/A011754) in the OEIS. There the following conjecture, which is based on the heuristic argument that TonyK explained nicely in the comments,, is mentioned:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}n = \frac{\log_2(3)}2>\frac34.$$

Since no paper on this subject is given at the OEIS, I suppose that nothing is known on this conjecture yet.